# Semiconducting properties of diamond imperfect crystals

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Suppose we want to make a diamond crystal and during the process point defects(lattice gaps) are created.

[image]

Which is the energy of the electrons?(red circles)Can we deliberately create those point defects in order to create electron donor atoms or to give diamond semiconducting properties?

Comment: One can certainly add point defects to a crystal in many ways, although one would not call it an alloy. In all the semiconductors I've worked with, point defects (from, e.g., ion implant) reduce carrier lifetimes. You don't want states in the gap since the are effective recombination centers.

Comment: @JonCuster i have updated the question in order to make more sense.